# Installing Fedora on External Hard Disk

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive

My question is if i install Fedora(or any other Linux distro) on my external HDD will the bootloader(grub) be installed on my Externall HDD. The problem is whenever i install linux on my laptop Hard Disk, grub failed to load windows.

So i thought of installing linux on an External HDD and then from bios choosing external HDD as boot option. Will it work? or grub will be installed on my main Disk, or that external HDD??

Thank You

Comment: Assuming the external harddisk is USB, and not eSATA: Can your BIOS boot from USB (all modern BIOS can)? If yes, you can install Grub on the external HDD, and boot from it.

Comment: Yes my external HDD is USB and my laptop can boot from USB. Thank You